# Help with segmentation fault in struct

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am having trouble debugging my code.  I have a struct and a 
function to compute the time difference entered in HH:MM:SS format. 
My code is:

```
const int hourConv = 3600; // used to get total hours from total seconds 
const int minConv = 60; 
struct MyTime { 
    int hours, minutes, seconds; 
}; 

MyTime *determineElapsedTime(const MyTime *time1, const MyTime *time2) 
{ 
        long timeOneSec = time1->hours*hourConv + time1->minutes*minConv + time1->seconds; 
        long timeTwoSec = time2->hours*hourConv + time2->minutes*minConv + time2->seconds; 
        long ans = timeTwoSec - timeOneSec; 
        cout << ans; 
        MyTime *timeDiff; 
        timeDiff->hours = ans / hourConv; 
        timeDiff->minutes = ans % hourConv / minConv; 
        timeDiff->seconds = ans % hourConv % minConv; 
        return timeDiff; 
}
```

I believe the problem to be with the 2nd to last line: 
`timeDiff->seconds = ans%hourConv%minConv;`
since when i comment that line out, 
I do not get a segmentation fault error.  But I don't understand why 
that line is invalid.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: @john you were a newbie at one point too... give the guy a break, it's not complex code.

Answer (score 6):

Your code contains:

```
MyTime *timeDiff;
timDiff->hours = ...
```

You have created a MyTime pointer but not allocated anything.  timeDiff is null at this point.

Comment: Is it null or a garbage value?

Comment: I believe in C/C++ the value is undefined at that point (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Ok that makes sense about it being null.  But what would I allocate it to at this point since I'm trying to create a new struct and a return a pointer to that struct?  Thanks!

Comment: Or are you supposed to say:
MyTime timeDiff
timeDiff.hours = ...
return &timeDiff;

although this way I get a compiler warning about returning the address of MyTime. Thanks!

Comment: You have to allocate a new instance of MyTime and assign it to timeDiff.  Then you can fill in the values and return the pointer to the allocated structure.  Remeber that the caller will need to free the struct or you will create a memory leak.

Comment: Just return timeDiff.  No need to return a reference to a pointer.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to access unallocated memory with the following code:

```
MyTime *timeDiff;
timeDiff->hours = ans / hourConv;
```

Although you could solve this by manually allocating the code using new, as:

```
MyTime *timeDiff = new MyTime;
timeDiff->hours = ans / hourConv;
```

I'd highly recommend changing your function to return the MyStruct by value, as a stack-allocated variable. I'd also suggest taking the arguments as pass-by-const reference:

```
MyTime determineElapsedTime(MyTime const &time1, MyTime const &time2)
{
     long timeOneSec = time1.hours*hourConv + time1.minutes*minConv + time1.seconds;
     long timeTwoSec = time2.hours*hourConv + time2.minutes*minConv + time2.seconds;
     long ans = timeTwoSec - timeOneSec;
     cout << ans;
     MyTime timeDiff;
     timeDiff.hours = ans / hourConv;
     timeDiff.minutes = ans % hourConv / minConv;
     timeDiff.seconds = ans % hourConv % minConv;
     return timeDiff;
}
```

Comment: The % hourConv is of no value in the assignment to timeDiff.seconds.  It will be hard for the compiler to spot that.

Answer (score 1):

Just one other remark:  use OOP in this case.  It will make your code so much more readable.  You'll end up with more time to think about uninitialized memory.

```
struct MyTime { 
    int hours, minutes, seconds; 
    int timeInSeconds() const {
        return hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds;
    }
    // the difference, in seconds
    int operator-( const MyTime other ) const {
        return timeInSeconds() - other.timeInSeconds();
    }
    void subtract( int seconds ) {
        seconds -= seconds;
        while( seconds < 0 ) { seconds += 60; --minutes; }
        while( minutes < 0 ) { minutes += 60; --hours; }
        assert( hours >= 0 );
    }
};
```

Next to that, it's a good idea to differentiate between time-differences and 'absolute' time values.  You *can* add two time diffs, but you cannot add two 'calendar' values.